# How to focus FRONT camera on device using iOS, swift?

Tags: ios, swift, camera

it seems that front camera doesn't support focusMode.

```
func configureDevice() {
    if let device = captureDevice {
        let focusMode: AVCaptureFocusMode = .AutoFocus
        if device.isFocusModeSupported(focusMode) {
            device.lockForConfiguration(nil)
            device.focusMode = AVCaptureFocusMode.AutoFocus
            device.unlockForConfiguration()
            println("configured device")
        }
    }
}
```

This code doesn't run because

```
if device.isFocusModeSupported(focusMode)
```

returns false.

But within the built-in-camera-app, front camera can focus on tap.

Is there any way implement tap-to-focus on the FRONT camera?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The front-facing camera **does not support** tap-to-focus on any iPhone. You can use `device.focusPointOfInterestSupported` property to check if you can do tap-to-focus (but you will get false, as with `isFocusModeSupported()`)

What you are seeing is tap-for-exposure, and you can check for that with `device.exposurePointOfInterestSupported`. Once you know that you can use it, use `device.exposurePointOfInterest` to set your PoI.

All the details of each mode is explained to detail in [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureDevice/exposurePointOfInterest)

Hope it helps!